# Is there a usage count for packages or programs?

Tags: package-management, cleanup, removing

**Motivation:**

I want to remove applications I do not use to speed up my package processing tasks like dist upgrades, regular updates, but also for saving disk space and other reasons. I know this is a complex topic so first I will ask my question and second I will give some answers I already found out.

**Question:**

How do I find out which package I did not used at all or for a long time? For example I always use the VLC so I could remove other players like Totem. Of course package dependencies could force me to have programs installed which I will never use.

**Notes:**

- Find the packages which consume much space via synaptic:

  Select "Status" in lower left, select "Installed" in upper left, sort
  column on "size" in upper right. Then you can decide which big
  packages you really need.
- Use `aptitude autoremove`
- Use `ubuntu-tweak`'s Janitor for removing old kernel packages, old configs, apt-cache entries, etc.
- Manually search for applications for a given task that you usually solve with your standard app. E.g. Movie player, Music player, Office program, Browser etc. (BTW: this is what I want to be helped with my question)
- When removing packages I always favour "apt-get purge" over "aptitude remove --purge" as aptitude often will also remove essential packages due to package dependencies. E.g. when removing "evolution" (as I use thunderbird) aptitude wants to remove also "ubuntu-desktop" and 756 other packages as well, while apt-get just removes evolution and its helping pacakges like evolution-common.
- Ubuntu lense gives me most recent used applications which are candidates for keeping :)
- Employ `deborphan` as I read in this related answer: [How do I clean up my harddrive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21587/how-do-i-clean-up-my-harddrive)
- I should certainly keep essential packages: [Keep only essential packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79665/keep-only-essential-packages)
- This question is pretty much a duplicate of [How to see what installed packages I have never used for cleaning purposes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107071/how-to-see-what-installed-packages-i-have-never-used-for-cleaning-purposes) but covering only few aspects. However one answer suggests to use a program called unusedpkg but the link seems down.
- There is also a program called Kleen http://code.google.com/p/kleen/ but it won't compile in 11.10. However I hacked it to compile but the results are unusable, as for example the g++ package was marked as not used for 203 days, but actually I used it seconds ago for compiling Kleen itself ;) So don't use this tool.
- On http://wiki.debian.org/DebianPackageInformation I read the the package popularity-contest will produce log files with usage statistics. Unfortunately I didn't enabled the popularity contest so I can't find this log file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you opt in, `popularity-contest` reports usage statistics back to Ubuntu, but it could also be used for purposes like yours. From it's man page:

> The  popularity-contest  command gathers information about Debian pack‐
>   ages installed on the system, and prints the name of the most  recently
>   used  executable  program  in that package as well as its last-accessed
>   time (atime) and last-attribute-changed time (ctime) to stdout.

The key word there is *executable*. So you'll probably get some false hits for data packages, etc.

So, for example, `popularity-contest | grep '<OLD>'` should give you a list of packages that have not been used for more than three months.

`popcon-largest-unused` gives you a list of unused package sorted by size.